# Change the footer in open edx editing the footer text in contact, home, etc

Tags: footer, openedx

I would like change the text and the link-text (Hoem, About, contact, donate) in the footer in open edx.
Could you explain me - where and how?

Wie ändere ich den Text in den Untermenüs im Footer von open edx?
Ich möchte den linktext zu den Unterseiten ändern (About, Home , Contact, Donate) und den Text in den jeweiligen Unterseiten einstellen.
Wie und wo mache ich das?

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop a theme for your Open edX instance. Then you can replace default template files.

[Here](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/changing_appearance/theming/create_theme.html) you can find more on Open edX theme developments.

If you are using the Open edX Tutor release; Check [here](https://docs.tutor.overhang.io/tutorials/theming.html?highlight=theme).